# How to set up a Report Manager in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: iframe, report-viewer, sharepiont

We have an SSRS report server installed on a separate machine in native mode. We have SharePoint 2010 installed on a different machine in native mode. Integration mode will not be an option.

I'd like to display the Report Manager from the SSRS site in an iFrame on the SharePoint site. I know that this can be done, but I don't know how. To my surprise, looking around on the internet has returned no resources.

Does anyone know of any tutorials or instructions they can share? Or give high level steps??

Again, the goal is to show the report manager in an iframe on SharePoint 2010. In the long run I'd like to also do some customization to the Report Manager UI. Also, I'm hoping this is all possible in SharePoint designer, and would **not** require Visual Studio.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Add a page in SharePoint, Edit Page, add PageViewer WebPart. Then configure the URL to Report Manager URL.

Answer (score 0):

Report Explorer and Report Viewer are SharePoint 2.0 Web Parts that were introduced in SQL Server 2000 Reporting Services Service Pack 2 (SP2) and continue to be available in current releases.

The Web Parts provide a way to view reports and explore the report server folder hierarchy from a SharePoint site.

- Report Explorer (SPExplorer.dwp) connects to Report Manager on the report server computer. You can browse available reports on a report server and subscribe to individual reports. If Report Builder is enabled and you have sufficient permissions, you can start Report Builder from the Report Explorer Web Part.
  Report Explorer displays the contents of a folder using a page in Report Manager. Access to individual items and folders throughout the report server folder hierarchy are controlled through role assignments on the report server. When you select a report, it opens in a new browser window. The HTML viewer on the report server displays the report and provides the report toolbar, not the Report Viewer Web Part. If you want to customize the toolbar settings, be sure to specify the URL access parameters on the report server.
- Report Viewer (SPViewer.dwp) displays a report and provides a toolbar that you can use to navigate pages, search for content, or export the report. You can add the Report Viewer Web Part to a Web Part page to always show a specific report on that page or you can connect it to Report Explorer to display reports that are opened through that Web Part.

**Installing WebPart**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159772.aspx

Comment: My fault. I should have mentioned explicitly that I did not want to use Report Explorer at all.  I just assumed this would be understood when I said I want to add Report Manager (a completely different option) to the page.